# Kafka .Net Produce vs ProduceAsync

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, log4net, confluent-platform, kafka-producer-api

I am using log4net (.Net) to write kafka appender and I am running into an issue where I cannot use await `ProduceAsync`.

Error

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked `<%@ Page Async="true" %>`. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it. ,
> StackTrace :    at
> `System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted(at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Create()`

Code

```
public class CustomAppender: AppenderSkeleton
{
     private IProducer<Null, string> p;

     public override void ActivateOptions()
     {
         // Setup kafka producer
     }

     protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
     {
         // Get JSON from application
         // Add additional data to the json 
         callBroker(json, topic);
     }

     private async void callBroker(string json, string topic)
     {
         var result = await p.ProduceAsync(Topic, new Message<Null, string>{Value=json});
     }          
}
```

I can return Task in my `callBroker` method but then there is no async override for Append method.

So my question is, Can I use Producer.Produce instead of `ProduceAsync` in a high volume environment? this program will be logging >500 messages/sec, is there a preference on which works better? I also need to handle some exceptions and take some action if it fails for specific error codes.

Answer (score 1):

### Sync version

```cs
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    CallBroker(topic, json);
}

private void CallBroker(string topic, string message)
{
    producer.Produce(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = message });
}
```

### Semi-async version

If you can't change the signature of the `Append` method
then you can call an async method in blocking mode via the following way:

```cs
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
    CallBrokerAsync(topic, json).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task CallBrokerAsync(string topic, string message)
{
    await producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = message });
}
```

Async shines when it is used all the way down (from the top most entry-point through all the layers till the lowest component which calls the async I/O operation)

As always measure, measure and measure to understand how does this change affect your application.